Show the user the id of the ticket submitted
I'm trying to create a form for 502 users to submit tickets on google forms to show the id of the ticket to the user as a confirmation message and to the team who is going to solve it the id is added correctly to the sheet but to the user it shows the id of the previously submitted form
this is the code i know the problem is in getLastRow() so how to make it work please
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const idColumn = 1;
  
   const ticketID = 'T-' + Utilities.formatString('%04d', lastRow);
  // const ticketID = lastRow
  
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, idColumn).setValue(ticketID);

  
  Logger.log('New ticket ID: ' + ticketID);

  // Update the confirmation message in the form
  const form = FormApp.openById('1oxTnzU5NRnzAlNFMmyehSf9vkORLs9vj5-XGGDvfqM0'); 
  const message = 'Thank you! Your ticket number is: ' + ticketID;
  form.setConfirmationMessage(message);
}




Use e.values instead of trying to get  the row.  You could also use e.range.rowStart if you wish the e.values has the actual values that were submitted for the current execution.

User ID of the Ticket Submitted on Google Forms Fixed
I tried it, and it worked for me. I included an additional ticket ID variable.The main issue was that the problem occurred because the header was delayed by the row.
Code:
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const idColumn = 1;
  
   const ticketID = 'T-' + (Utilities.formatString('%04d', lastRow));
 
   // I added this ticketIdDuplicate variable to get the desired response in Google Forms.
   const ticketIdDuplicate = 'T-' + (Utilities.formatString('%04d', lastRow + 1));
 
 
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, idColumn).setValue(ticketID);
 
  
  Logger.log('New ticket ID: ' + ticketID);
 
  // Update the confirmation message in the form
  const form = FormApp.openById('1oxTnzU5NRnzAlNFMmyehSf9vkORLs9vj5-XGGDvfqM0');
 
  // Insert the duplicate variable here.
  const message = 'Thank you! Your ticket number is: ' + ticketIdDuplicate;
  form.setConfirmationMessage(message);
}

Sample Output:


Reference:
Expressions and Operators

thank you so much but what if two people submitted the ticket at the same time they are going to have the same ticket id

Yes, that may happen and would be considered a new question since it's not part of the initial problem. Please post it as a new one if you'd like the community members to take a look at it, and if my answer was useful for you in the initial issue, consider checking out What should I do when someone answers my question?

I disagree with asking the OP to post a new question, as it makes common sense to avoid displaying the same ticked ID to two different users.

I understand your opinion, but the initial question is intended to be a fix on how the ticket ID would show up properly when a user says submitted a form, not when two users at the same time would open the form and submit it which is why I proposed a new question. It seems that the new questions is more on how would a Google Forms OnFormSubmit() will work in case a simultaneous trigger happens.

As you have seen, it's not possible to dynamically set the form confirmation message. The FormApp.Form.setConfirmationMessage doesn't change the confirmation message shown to the current form submitter because this change occurs after the confirmation message is shown.
Adding the following ticked ID might not be a good idea, as you might get more than one user opening the form with a ticket ID already shown. If you need to give the ticket ID to the form submitter, consider asking them for their email and sending the ticket ID through email.
Notably, Google Forms is not a great fit for use cases like this. A better option might be to create a web app, but this requires more work than creating a form in Google Forms.
